# Using the same variable in 2 sections of code inside a single sub MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am making an Access form that will allow the user to process contract upgrades, and within the form I have a button that changes 3 dates for each contract, the date connected, end date, and earliest upgrade date.

When changing the end date, I use this code to actually change the date:

```
[End Date] = DateAdd("m", Number, FirstDate)
```

The end date being the date I want to change, then adding to the date using `DateAdd`, changing the month of the date, with a number that the user inputs, usually 24, then the FirstDate is the current end date. FirstDate is set as a variable at the beginning of the code.

What I want to change it to is this:

```
[End Date] = DateAdd("m", Number, Startdate)
```

Where it does everything the same, however using a different variable that is used earlier in the code to change the start date of the contract, which does work in that section of code, but when I try to use it again here the code crashes.

This also still happens even when I change the `Startdate` to [Date Connected].

Can anyone help me figure why the code won't use the `Startdate` variable a second time in the section of code after the first one.

This is the whole private sub that the code takes place in, this being the new code I want to use:

```
Private Sub cmdUpgrade_Click()

Dim Startdate As String
Dim Number As String
Dim Tariff As String

Startdate = InputBox("Enter Start Date (00/00/0000):", "Inputbox")
If StrPtr(Startdate) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You pressed Cancel" 'Option 1
Else
If Startdate = "" Then
MsgBox "Input Left Empty" ' Option 2
Else
[Date Connected] = Startdate
End If
End If


Number = InputBox("Enter Contract Length + Rollover:", "Inputbox")
If StrPtr(Number) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You pressed Cancel" 'Option 1
Else
If Number = "" Then
MsgBox "Input Left Empty" ' Option 2
Else
**[End Date] = DateAdd("m", Number, Startdate)**
[Earliest Upgrade] = DateAdd("d", -180, [End Date])
End If
End If

Tariff = InputBox("Enter Tarrif", "Inputbox")
If StrPtr(Tarrif) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You pressed Cancel" 'Option 1
Else
If Tariff = "" Then
MsgBox "Input Left Empty" ' Option 2
Else
[Current Talk Plan] = Tariff
End If
End If

Forms!frmForecast.Form.Requery
DoCmd.SearchForRecord , , acFirst, "Year([Earliest Upgrade]) = Year(Date())                 
And Month([Earliest Upgrade]) = Month(Date())"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always handle dates as dates, not strings. Also, it doesn't matter if the user presses Cancel or OK for an empty input:

```
Dim Startdate As Date
Dim Enddate As Date
Dim TestDate As String
Dim Number As String
Dim Tariff As String

TextDate = InputBox("Enter Start Date (00/00/0000):", "Inputbox")
If TextDate = "" Then
    MsgBox "No date entered" 'Option 1
ElseIf Not IsDate(TextDate) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid date" ' Option 2
Else
    Startdate = DateValue(TextDate)
    [Date Connected] = Startdate
End If

<snip>

Enddate = DateAdd("m", Number, Startdate)
[End Date] = Enddate
[Earliest Upgrade] = DateAdd("d", -180, Enddate)
```